# View function prototypes in C

Tags: c

Often during programming contests I forget which library contains which function. Hence I require some C code which can print the available functions with a specific library. eg. usage:

`showAvailFunctions("stdlib.h")`

and it would print all the available functions with `stdlib.h` library

Comment: Open up the file "stdlib.h"
And read it's prototypes... (You can also do this by code)

Comment: That's something that your IDE should do, though it can also be done programmatically.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if you could just use your functions and then have your IDE add all required headers?

Comment: Man pages also contain all this info

Comment: If `vi` or `eclipse` don't solve your problem, you might want to check [`doxygen`](http://www.doxygen.org/)

Comment: I want the results in the program output.

Comment: Why do you want C code? Anyway, using Clang compiler framework is probably the most robust way to create the function you desire.  However, if you really want what you are asking for, a C function, then this question is way too broad for SO.

Comment: Some modern compilers, such as `clang` even warn you, for example, not to implicitly declare `malloc()` (if you did so), but to include `stdlib.h` instead.

Comment: If the goal is to help you remember what to include, then the man pages or google are your friends. If the goal is to figure out where a particular prototype comes from in your own c file, you need to dump the preprocessor output.

Comment: @Arkadiy okay so how can I "dump the preprocessor output" to stdout.

Comment: Please google "dump preprocessor output"? In gcc it's -E switch.

Comment: but during contests I only have access to my editor and a compile button which automatically compiles so I cannot provide custom flags or access any other file. I just have the editor and the output screen and a compile and run button.

Comment: So basically you're proposing to write a *header file parser* from scratch at the beginning of the contest. Is that right? May I suggest that it's easier just to memorize the names of all the header files, and just include all of them.

Comment: @user3386109 yeah you can say that, I don't know if thats possible in an coding contest. But as far as this discussion is going it seems there is no direct way and I need to parse or read the header files (which wouldn't be possible since I don't know the path to the header files.)

Comment: It would be great if I could somehow derive the path from the header file's name and then use that path to open the header file to read its contents.

Comment: You would need the include path from the environment, and/or the include path that's passed to the compiler on the command line. Even then, it's possible that you won't have any access to the directory that contains the header files.

Comment: yes I don't have access to any documentation.

Comment: some 99% of the header files are located in `/usr/include`, with some in `/usr/local/include`   Then any files you write will be where ever you placed them (usually in the same directory or sub directory of your top level project directory.

Comment: What about `grep function_name_in_question /usr/include/ -rw`?

Answer (score 1):

Create a C program file with the `include` directive for the include file you want to see.

For instance:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

Compile with Preprocessor output to generate a file, usually a file with an extension of `.i` and you will have the complete contents of the include file.

For Visual Studio, you may need to indicate whether you want to keep the comments or not.

The output file should appear in your working directory.

A more involved example of an approach is as follows. This is a C source text file which does a series of includes with special markers to show what is where.

The program at the bottom of the source file is a simple filter program which reads the C Preprocessor file generated and removes most of the clutter such as blank lines or those "#line " lines of output which specify a line number and the file it came from.

You will need to add whatever include files you want to see. Then compile it twice, once with C Preprocessor output enabled to generate a file containing the C Preprocessor output and once with C Preprocessor output disabled to generate an actual executable file. Your C compiler may provide options to do both steps in a single compile. I could not see how to do that with Visual Studio 2013.

Here is an example source file. I expect you may need to tailor this for your compiler and development environment. This compiles and generates output with Visual Studio 2013. I created a simple `.bat` file which runs this application from the command line and redirect STDOUT to a text file that contains the filtered C Preprocessor output.

```
#define MAKE_SEP_STRING "<!-- #$%^&*()_+-=qwrtv -->"
#define MAKE_SEP_STRING_END "<!--END #$%^&*()_+-=qwrtv -->"
#define MAKE_SEP_BEGIN(x)  static const char X_##x [] = MAKE_SEP_STRING #x;
#define MAKE_SEP_END

MAKE_SEP_BEGIN(stdio);
#include <stdio.h>
MAKE_SEP_BEGIN(stdlib);
#include <stdlib.h>
MAKE_SEP_END

#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("output file must be specified.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        char *sep = MAKE_SEP_STRING_END;  // if we want to determine where each file begins or ends.
        FILE *pFile;

        fopen_s(&pFile, argv[1], "r");

        if (pFile) {
            char  hugeBuffer[4096];

            // read through the C Preprocessor output file and eliminate empty lines.
            // there can be a lot of empty lines.
            while (fgets(hugeBuffer, 4000, pFile)) {
                if (strlen(hugeBuffer) > 5) {
                    // discard all those tons of #line n text lines generated by the Preprocessor
                    if (strncmp(hugeBuffer, "#line ", 6) == 0) continue;
                    if (strcmp(hugeBuffer, sep) == 0)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    printf("%s\n", hugeBuffer);
                }
            }
            fclose(pFile);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I want the results in program output itself

Comment: can you please elaborate with a working code...

Comment: @Himanshu, I have added an example. You will probably need to tailor this example.